# multiline table header in wicket

Tags: wicket

Similar to this.

We are using sortable table header. But it does not support multiline header.

[How can I construct a table header than spans multiple rows in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680044/how-can-i-construct-a-table-header-than-spans-multiple-rows-in-html)

Comment: What components do you use? I thought `DataTable` supports adding multiple top and bottom headers.

Comment: @RobAu We are using https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/table/HeadersToolbar.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll out your own Toolbar with extension of the IColumn impls that supports this, e.g. https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/ebc873384dea5ee0cf9ab6f621a3419862a6c8f1/datatables-parent/datatables/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/datatables/columns/SpanHeadersToolbar.java#L97-L99.

If you think this deserves to be supported by Wicket then please raise an issue in JIRA!
Thanks!